# How do I get the PID of a command nested within the quotes?

Tags: bash

I am trying to get the PID of the command within the quotes (e.g. `some-command-here`) *whilst being able to interact with the process spawned by* `some-command-here`:

```
x-terminal-emulator -e "some-command-here" &> /dev/null
```

For example, sometimes `apt full-upgrade -y` can require user input, thus it is important that the process spawned by `some-command-here` remain interactive.

Comment: So you need `pid` of a running process? `pidof` is one way to get it. Call `xterm -e apt full-upgrade &` to run `xterm` in parallel, then `pidof apt` to get all `pid`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, with a bit more testing and research, it seems that this task can be accomplished utilizing `ps ax`, `grep`, `xargs` & `cut`.

```
ps ax | grep -v "grep" | grep "sh -c" | grep "some-command-here" | xargs | cut -d ' ' -f 1
```

### How does this work?

When `x-terminal-emulator` is passed `-e` it spawns a new shell window and passes it the command within the quotes. In order to execute the command, it passes the new shell the command `sh -c` along with the quoted command. Thus, `sh -c some-command-here`. Which is utilized within the searching of the PID above.

`ps ax` lists the currently running processes.

`grep -v "grep"` searches the output and removes any processes that contain `grep` as a process simply because when we launch this query, a process under `grep` will be created.

`grep "sh -c"` searches the output for a process that contains `sh -c`.

`grep "some-command-here"` searches the output of `ps ax` for a process that matches what is within the quotes.

`xargs` converts the output of `grep "sh -c some-command-here"` into a space delimited list.

`cut -d ' ' -f 1` removes the spaces and grabs the first result. Which returns the PID of the process in question.

Comment: Maybe take a look at `pgrep`

Answer (score 0):

```
x-terminal-emulator -e "some-command-here & echo $! >/tmp/pid" &> /dev/null
cat /tmp/pid
```

... or get rid of the &>/dev/null:

```
x-terminal-emulator -e "some-command-here & echo $!"
```

Comment: This solution kind of defeats the purpose of using `x-terminal-emulator -e` because the command gets executed but then exits immediately after execution because `some-command-here &` gets moved to the background which executes in less than a second and `echo $! >/tmp/pid` finishes within the same time. I need to be able to **interact** with the process spawned by `some-command-here`. For example, `apt full-upgrade -y` can sometimes require user input.